# How to use a serializer with foreign keys for Django rest api?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have two django models with a many-to-one relationship (one venue can have many events). I want to produce a page which has all the attributes from each event, and the information about its venue from the venue model.

Here is my **models.py** file:

```
class Venue(models.Model):
    venueID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    venueName = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    venueImage = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.venueName


class Event(models.Model):
    venueID = models.ForeignKey(
        Venue, related_name='events', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    venueName = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    eventID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    artistName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    eventName = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.eventName
```

Here is my **serializers.py** file

```
class VenueSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Venue
        fields = "__all__"


class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = "__all__"


class VenueForGivenEventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    events = EventSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Venue
        fields = '__all__'
```

My **urls.py** file: (I'm pretty sure that this is not the issue)

```
from django.urls import path
from django.urls.conf import include
from .views import EventViewSet
from .views import VenueViewSet
from .views import VenueForGivenEventViewSet
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter


router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('events', EventViewSet)
router.register('venues', VenueViewSet)
router.register('fullevents', VenueForGivenEventViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls))
]
```

At the moment, when accessing /fullevents, I currently get an error saying:

> int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Venue'

I have no error for /events or /venues.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you share `VenueForGivenEventViewSet`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was actually in **views.py**

```
class VenueForGivenEventViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
```

`queryset = Venue.objects.all()`

```
serializer_class = VenueForGivenEventSerializer
```